# Visual Studio 2008 redistributable OpenMP library as merge module

Tags: visual-c++, wix, windows-installer, openmp, redistributable

I have a project that uses OpenMP and therefore links against `vcomp90.dll`.

Now I'd like to create an installer (using WiX), and am left wondering how to add this library to my project properly. It appears the regular MSM with the redistributable runtime is missing this DLL.

What is the correct way to add this library to my package?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used a merge module till date which includes vccomp90.dll. 
However, i do see a lot of posts where people have used an equivalent merge module which includes the so called file. As per Microsoft's own literature, an equivalent merge module named Microsoft_VC90_OpenMP_x86.msm exits which should include vccomp90.dll. I did try to search for this merge module on my system and could not find it. Perhaps, it needs an optional component of Visual studio that i might not have installed.

Nevertheless,as i was searching for this merge module, i stumbled upon a text called redist.txt. redist.txt is part of the Visual studio install folders(Be remember to check both your  windows drive as well as the installation drive, in case you have installed Visual Studio in a non windows drive).

The redist.txt has the following text contained in it:
***For your convenience, we have provided the following folders for use when redistributing VC++ runtime files. Subject to the license terms for the software, you may redistribute the folder (unmodified) in the application local folder as a sub-folder with no change to the folder name. You may also redistribute all the files (*.dll and *.manifest) within a folder, listed below the folder for your convenience, as an entire set.***

**\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP\
 vcomp90.dll
 Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.manifest

\VC\redist\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP\
 vcomp90.dll
 Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.manifest

\VC\redist\ia64\Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP\
 vcomp90.dll
 Microsoft.VC90.OpenMP.manifest**

This gives you two options:
-Include the file and its corresponding manifest file as part of a custom merge module and include it in your product. I prefer this approach as you can re-use the merge  module elsewhere for your products.
-Include the file and its manifest file directly in your msi package.

The other option is to make use of a bootstrapper for your msi file and run the VC redistributable installer as part of your installation process.